# How to add a half circle at the bottom middle of my header?

Tags: html, css, shapes, css-shapes

Here is how I want it to look:

[image: header with half circle at bottom]

I realize this is an ugly mockup and obviously when I do it for real the proportions will look better, but I am wondering how you would go about doing this with CSS.

fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/bU3QS/1/

```
<div class="header">
    </div>

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 10000;
    height: 110px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `:after` pseudo element:

```
.header:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 50%;    /* Makes the element circular */
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
}
```

For this solution, `overflow: hidden;` has been removed from the `.header` CSS.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t97AX/

Here's another approach, that doesn't rely on the width of the semicircle to center it properly:

```
.header:after {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    top: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
}
```

The fiddle (semicircle red for the sake of clarity): http://jsfiddle.net/x4mdC/

More on `:before` and `:after`: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#before-and-after

Comment: This way, you don't need to add further elements inside the header.

Comment: Upvote because this is by far the most elegant solution, and no additional markup is needed (plus, stylistic items like this should not be in the markup to begin with) :)

Comment: Use `border-radius: 50%;` just to be sure when the dimensions are edited.

Comment: I can't believe I never thought of that. Updated.

Comment: @BramVanroy to make a perfect circle it would want to be `border-radius: 100%;` but I should have thought of that too; changed, my fiddle to use that clear improvement.

Comment: @NicklasNygren upvoting, while not the way I would want it for my site I like it as a different method of doing the same thing in a way I wouldn't automatically think of.

Comment: Thanks @Nick! I'm pretty sure the `border-radius` doesn't have to be the full width of the element though, as it is a radius, and not a diameter. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Nicklas see my answer, very similar to yours but border radius is only half the width. I made a semicircle instead of a circle.

Comment: Is there a better way for centering this for different sizes of half circles?

Comment: @Michael very nice. But that way the `border-radius` percent solution won't work.

Comment: @Steveai: yes there is. I've updated the answer. See the second example!

Answer (score 2):

Use `:after` and `border-radius` to create the semicircle.

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 110px;
    }
.header:after {
    content: '';
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    top: 110px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bU3QS/2/

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="circle">
    </div>
    </div>
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    height: 110px;
}

.circle {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top:45px;
}
```

in action: http://jsfiddle.net/NickWilde/ngcce/

Comment: This should not be the answer, unless you need to interact with the circle using javascript. It is not content but decoration and should use an `:after` pseudo element.

Comment: If it was on my own site I would definitely use a div and then style it rather than using `after` so that I can see without going into the style external file why the heck there is a circle somewhere. After may have it's uses but I don't like there not being a relatively clear reason for everything without switching back and forth between files.

Comment: You can see the pseudo element on most browser debugging tools (F12)

Comment: Yes I know; Unless there is some performance improvement that I don't know about, to me it is a personal preference - I mean if I saw a good argument for why using :after is always better then I might change my preference.