# How to make CSS separator half-circle?

Tags: css, html

I have mockup like this [image: Half Circle]

And I'm trying to add this in my code

**HTML**

```
<section id="screens-three" class="clearfix">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 class="maintitle text-center">Test</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="screens-four" class="clearfix">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 class="maintitle">01Designs</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The problem? How to make a separator like an image above?

Comment: What CSS have you tried?

Comment: You cannot (as this is not really half-circle but some half-oval). Use image.

Comment: The problem is the round corner on the left and right (what Bhojendra said). But something like a simple half circle [is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033468/how-to-add-a-half-circle-at-the-bottom-middle-of-my-header).

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Ovals aren’t really a problem in CSS (I also don’t think it should be _exactly_ that oval — maybe it could as well be a circle in the final product), the rounded corners are the worrying part…

Comment: I don't want to downvote question because of its problem of someone, but without OP's effort i don't want to give suggestions.

Comment: @Manwal Don’t worry, I downvoted for you. If a question lacks research effort, you downvote it. That’s what the tooltip for the downvote button says.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create exactly as your image. For this, you need to style the separator using image.

For half-circle, you can use:

```css
.separator {
    position: relative;
    background: #000;
    height: 50px;
}

.separator::before{
    width: 30px;
    height: 15px; /* half of the width */
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    /* play with the value like 10px 12px 
       to get something like your image */
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    border-top: 0;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0px; /* use negative shift if you get something closer to image */
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="separator"></div>
```

Comment: You can still use the `transform` `scale` function to make it an oval. (And you can use `transform: translateX(-50%);` to actually center it.)

Comment: Even then couldn't create as exactly as image.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="absolute-div">

</div>
<div class="first-div">
</div>
<div class="second-div">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.first-div
{
  height:50px;
  background-color:#666;
}
.second-div
{
  height:100px;
  background-color:#000;
}
.absolute-div{
  height:30px;
  margin-left:50%;
  position:absolute;
  width:30px;
  margin-top:40px;
  background:#666;
  border-radius:50px;

}
.container{
  position: relative;
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2qydgx1/).

Comment: That doesn’t look like the desired shape at all.

Comment: @Xufox: True. But that is the best I could do.